# SharePoint Online - Edit columns in Document Library

Tags: document-library, document

I have added a site column into a document library and whenever I create a new row, it automatically loads up a word document and then saves the row (as expected)

However, this additional column stated above is a yes/no column which basically states if this document (row) is active or not. But I can never seem to set it. Is this by design or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: The SharePoint checkbox has never been any good. Mostly because it uses TRUE/FALSE or 1/0 to set the value. Better of with a mandatory choice field with yes/no and set it to yes by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK you can edit the YES/NO field but you need to go to the properties of the row (right clicking the row -> Details -> Properties), something I never had done before. So yes, is it done by design.

Answer (score 0):

Go To Library settings and click on this column which is causing issue. See if you have enabled default value for that column. Disable it and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, When I go to the site column it just says "Default setting: Yes or No" there's nothing about disabling it.